# A simple hello-world with djinni is stuck at building djinni. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, djinni

I am new to djinni and I was checking how it works and wanted to do some `hello-world` stuff. So from their [github repo](https://github.com/sulewicz/djinni-react-native), I copied the following snippet:

```
# Multi-line comments can be added here. This comment will be propagated
# to each generated definition.
my_enum = enum {
    option1;
    option2;
    option3;
}

my_flags = flags {
  flag1;
  flag2;
  flag3;
  no_flags = none;
  all_flags = all;
}
```

named this file `hello-world.djinni` and run the following command:

```
 src/run --java-out ./ --va-package com.faze.ch.rt --cpp-out ./ --jni-out ./ --idl hello-world.djinni
```

But I am not sure this was correct? It has been stuck at the following:

```
Building Djinni...
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
```

and I do not think it will make progress. I just wanted to generate stuff in multiple languages and see how it looks. Is there something I am missing? I have forked [djinni react native](https://github.com/sulewicz/djinni-react-native) and kept the `hello-world.djinni` file at the root.

Comment: It looks like some network issue (firewall) or configuration. I've never had a problem with running djinni for the first time. Also, I never tried that fork. You could check out djinni from https://github.com/dropbox/djinni . Btw., if your goal is just generate JNI bindings, you could try SWIG instead.